# Searching the web for local host

Tags: localhost, local

When I am trying to open localhost3000 or any port on my computer It does a search instead. It does this on chrome and safari but not fire fox. I am not sure how to fix this as chrome is my main browser.[screen shoot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTNX1.png)

Comment: This is a browser configuration issue.

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the `localhost:3000` with `http://`? So: `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Would be useful if you shown print screen of how the address is entered in the browser but from your description is looks like you forgot to add a colon between `localhost` and `3000` - should be `localhost:3000`